# Can Prepare Content option be added to a Module?

Tags: module, joomla-3.6

With a Custom HTML module, there is an Option and you can select Yes or No for Prepare Content. This is needed if you have something like the content plugin I developed to acknowledge this, as it does in Joomla Articles:

```
{myplugin}ABCDE1234,"Flux Capacitor"{/myplugin}
```

For example, there is a module mod_articles_latest, and I wish to add the Prepare Content option to this, so that when it is showing Joomla Articles it will process the above plugin example.

I found this link about Triggering Content Plugins, but I'm unsure if simply adding this code to mod_articles_latest, will make it work:

```
$text = JHtml::_('content.prepare', $text);
```

https://docs.joomla.org/Triggering_content_plugins_in_your_extension

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "Prepare Content" do and when should it be used?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/22152/what-does-prepare-content-do-and-when-should-it-be-used)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `JHtml::_('content.prepare', $text);` should do what you want as long as the original `$text` contains your content tag.

The module `mod_articles_latest` outputs by default just the title of an article. If you want to modify the template of the module just for your site, you can use template overrides for the modification. If you want to offer your plugin for others this will not work. In that case, I recommend to create and provide your own version of those modules.

Comment: I should clarify, I'm working with a RSJOOMLA layout they did for a template for mod_articles_latest and it shows the first 250 characters of the Joomla Article.